# how to get perf to decode symbols for hadoop java code

Tags: java, linux, performance, ubuntu, hadoop

I'm using perf tools on ubuntu 12.04 to profile system level performance of hadoop 2.4.1 map/reduce jobs by doing:

```
perf record -ag -F 100 sleep 60
```

My goal is to determine which processes/routines are consuming the cpu and identify candidates for optimization.

Kernel symbols are decoded correctly, but java code is not.  Perf report looks something like:

```
Samples: 39K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 11326629675790000f9f0                                                                                                                                  â
+  10.64%           java  perf-9201.map               [.] 0x00007eff6c188127                                                                                                                                   
+  10.57%           java  perf-8988.map               [.] 0x00007f71ac7b9a29                                                                                                                                   
+   9.91%           java  perf-9077.map               [.] 0x00007fa9e92073e0                                                                                                                                   
+   9.77%           java  perf-9025.map               [.] 0x00007f849cdf41a9                                                                                                                                   
+   9.26%           java  perf-8747.map               [.] 0x00007f078c6bda82                                                                                                                                   
+   7.85%           java  perf-31343.map              [.] 0x00007f6671041cb4                                                                                                                                   
+   5.81%           java  perf-8835.map               [.] 0x00007f5df0d5afc4                                                                                                                                   
+   5.78%           java  liblzo2.so.2.0.0            [.] lzo1x_decompress                                                                                                                                     
+   2.61%           java  [kernel.kallsyms]           [k] copy_user_generic_string                                                                                                                             
+   1.58%           java  libc-2.15.so                [.] 0x000000000008ce40                                                                                                                                   
+   0.93%           java  perf-9677.map               [.] 0x00007f7c81012887                                                                                                                                   
+   0.86%        swapper  [kernel.kallsyms]           [k] intel_idle                                                                                                                                           
+   0.69%           java  libjvm.so                   [.] SpinPause
```

So the question is, how do I get perf to decode the symbols for the java code?

Comment: Depends on what JVM vendor you have. If it is oracle, you can send out a nice mail if Oracle wants to give you the source/dbg symbols.

Comment: Yes, it is oracle.  Guess I may need to switch to openjdk?  My impression was that it would be better to use their version, but now I'm reconsidering...

Comment: Why do you want to look at the JVM? Do you think the bottleneck is within the java interpreter?

Comment: Not interested in the JVM, but I would like to see a decode of symbols for the java code for the map/reduce (wordcount) code that's running. In the output above, it appears that the undecoded symbols are in the Apache hadoop code (e.g. perf-####.map) rather than in the jvm.

Comment: You need a Java Profiler then, not a native one. [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the perf-$pid.map objects that show up in the perf output are associated with JIT compiled java code.  In order for perf to be able to decode those symbols, the java code needs to produce /tmp/perf-$pid.map symbol map files.

There is a [perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jrudolph/perf-map-agent) library on github that can be used to generate the symbol map files for JITed code.  With the library in place, add -agentpath:<dir>/libperfmap.so to the java command line.

To make hadoop jobs generate the symbol maps, add lines such as the following to hadoop-env.sh:

```
export HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS="-agentpath:/usr/lib/oprofile/libjvmti_oprofile.so $HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS"
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentpath:/usr/lib/libperfmap.so $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
```